# QML: Simple word wrap with TextEdit element?

Tags: word-wrap, qml, qt-quick, textedit

I'm just a beginner to QML and I wanted to make a simple example, which contains just one Rectangle with a TextEdit element:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400; height: 400
    color: "lightblue"

    TextEdit {
        x: 50; y: 100; width: 300; height: 300
        text: "editable text editable text editable text editable text "
        font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pixelSize: 32
    }
}
```

The idea here is to just have a few lines displayed that the user can change or add. I just would like it to display it as multiple word-wrapped lines instead of just on a single line. I don't even need a scrollbar. Since TextEdit does not have a WrapMode property, how can I do this? :-(

Thanks!
Nina

Comment: there should be a ";" between the height and color properties of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEdit **has** a wordWrap property.
See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qml-textedit.html#wrapMode-prop.

if you add

```
wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
```

to the TextEdit component the text is wrapped to multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Strangely I kept getting errors when I tried to type out this property first time around. But switching to design mode and then back to edit mode in qt creator helped! :o)  -Nina